# How can I bring a window to the foreground using win32gui in python, even if the window is minimized?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, winapi, win32gui

I need help bringing a minimized window to the foreground using win32gui in python, on a Windows 10 machine.  I'm probably missing something pretty simple, but I have not been able to find the answer here or in other forums.

The attached code attempts to activate a window and send a keystroke.  It does exactly what I want and expect...UNLESS the window I'm trying to activate is minimized.  It works fine if the window is behind another window, or side by side, or tiled.  But if it is minimized, it seems that the window is never found and the keystroke does not get sent to the window.  The script runs without error.

Other than making minor edits, I did not write this script.  So, I'm not super familiar with the methods being used.  But it is extremely close to doing exactly what I want it to do, so I'm just looking for someone to help me make the proper adjustments to the script.  Thanks.

```
import win32gui
import re
import win32api
import win32con
import time


class WindowMgr:
      """Encapsulates some calls to the winapi for window management"""
      def __init__ (self):
        """Constructor"""
        self._handle = None

      def find_window(self, class_name, window_name = None):
        """find a window by its class_name"""
        self._handle = win32gui.FindWindow(class_name, window_name)

      def _window_enum_callback(self, hwnd, wildcard):
        '''Pass to win32gui.EnumWindows() to check all the opened windows'''
        if re.match(wildcard, str(win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))) != None:
            self._handle = hwnd

      def find_window_wildcard(self, wildcard):
        self._handle = None
        win32gui.EnumWindows(self._window_enum_callback, wildcard)

      def set_foreground(self):
         """put the window in the foreground"""
        win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(self._handle)


w = WindowMgr()
w.find_window_wildcard(".*Notepad.*")
w.set_foreground()
time.sleep(1)

Xkey = 0x58 #VirtualKey Code

win32api.keybd_event(Xkey,0,0,0) # holds the key down
time.sleep(1) # waits 1 second
win32api.keybd_event(Xkey,0,win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0) # releases the key
```

Comment: Windows bringing themselves to the foreground are annoying to me, because they disturb me while I'm doing something else; I'd suggest you to make the icon on the taskbar blink, or show some kind of notification in for example bottom right corner of the screen. It's much less disruptive.

Comment: Wouldn't `pywin32` tag be suitable? If so, you can [edit] your question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  In my case, bringing the window to the front is exactly what I want to do.  My posted code is just a simplified example for testing purposes.  My ultimate purpose involves passing focus (and data) from one application to another.  I want to make it as seamless as possible for the end user.

Comment: I will try to add some more relevant tags, thanks.